# Get Cover Photo using Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my Android application, I am trying to get the cover photo of the user from his Facebook account.

I can get the profile picture by using the below code.

```
profilePicUrl = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large");

profilePicBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(profilePicUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) specifies the following for retrieving the cover photo.

> The user's cover photo (must be explicitly requested using
>   fields=cover parameter)
>
> Requires access_token
>
> Returns : array of fields id, source, and
>   offset_y

So, the structure of the JSON response would be something like this.

```
{
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "10151008748223553",
      "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/391237_10151008748223553_422785532_n.jpg",
      "offset_y": 0
   },
   "id": "19292868552"
}
```

I am pretty new to Facebook Graph API and hence do not have much knowledge on how to go about this.

I tried this `coverPicUrl = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/cover?type=large");`

and also this `coverPicUrl = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/fields=cover");`

But I have not been able to get the cover picture of the user profile.

Searching online also did not yield any fruitful results.

Any help would indeed be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "source" tag (JSONObject) is nested inside another JSONObject, the "cover" tag. To parse this result, you will have to use something like this:

```
JSONObject JOSource = JOCover.optJSONObject("cover");
String coverPhoto = JOSource.getString("source");
```

The `JOCover` used in the example assumes that you already have a `JSONOBject (JOCover)` to parse the root. You can substitute your own `JSONObject` in its place.

The "source" tag cannot be accessed directly as it is nested in the "cover" tag. You will have to use "`.optJSONObject("cover")`". I have seen people use `.getString` instead of the `.optJSONObject` but I have never used it. Choose what works for you.

**EDIT**

As per your request for a solution using Graph API, I am editing the earlier solution and replacing it with the Graph API solution.

Preferably, in an `AsyncTask`, use this code in the `doInBackground`:

```
String URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + THE_USER_ID + "?fields=cover&access_token=" + Utility.mFacebook.getAccessToken();

String finalCoverPhoto;

try {

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

    if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());

        JSONObject JODetails = new JSONObject(result);

        if (JODetails.has("cover")) {
            String getInitialCover = JODetails.getString("cover");

            if (getInitialCover.equals("null")) {
                finalCoverPhoto = null;
        } else {
            JSONObject JOCover = JODetails.optJSONObject("cover");

            if (JOCover.has("source"))  {
                finalCoverPhoto = JOCover.getString("source");
            } else {
                finalCoverPhoto = null;
            }
        }
    } else {
        finalCoverPhoto = null;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

I have tested this solution and works perfectly. You will have to add any addition `fields` to the base URL that are required for your activity. For the sake of testing, I used just the `fields=cover`

And in the `onPostExecute`, do your thing to display the cover picture. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please tell me the URL which I should be using to make the request ? I keep on getting this error. `{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /field=cover",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}`

Comment: I get this error too. `org.json.JSONException: No value for source`

Comment: @swayam: When using the `/field=????`, you have to provide the access token too. I have added more code which should ideally do the trick for you.

Comment: You code looks pretty good but actually I am trying to get my hands on the Graph API. Could you please help me out using the API instead of making FQL statements ? Your code works but I am trying to learn the API and it would really be great if you could help.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: Fetching Cover Photo using Facebook API and endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=cover` no longer works as on 20th Dec 2014.

It was supposed to give following response:

```
{
   "cover": {
   "cover_id": "10151008748223553",
   "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/391237_10151008748223553_422785532_n.jpg",
   "offset_y": 0
   },
   "id": "19292868552"
}
```

But now it just gives User's `id`:

```
{
  "id": "19292868552"
}
```

Verified this using [Graph Tool explorer 2.2](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) using `me?fields=cover`.

Comment: This is no longer working @YangShun ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: This is still working as at Sept 14th 2016, but you need to apply the user_photos scope for your app.

Answer (score 1):

You have already cover photo Url just read that String from the Json array, from that String you can get the Cover photo. 
this is the cover photo url

```
"source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/391237_10151008748223553_422785532_n.jpg",
```

like this you can get the Image Url form the Json Object.

```
String cover_photo = JsonObject.getString("source");
```

Comment: What URL should I be using ? I am confused. I keep on getting this error as reply. `{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /field=cover",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a similar feature in my app. This is how I did it, using FQL:

```
String cover_photo = jsonObj.getJSONObject("pic_cover").getString("source");
```

This gives the url to a cover photo, since the `source` tag is nested within the `pic_cover` object, which can then be set to an `ImageView` using a library like Universal Image Loader

Answer (score 0):

```
object.getJSONObject("cover").getString("source")
```