# Android - Facebook API giving empty result for user cover photo

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the user's cover photo and show it at the top of a layout. I'm using AsyncTask to run the API call to Facebook. The code I'm using to get the Facebook data is

```
JSONObject json = null;
response = Utility.facebook.request("me?fields=cover");
json = Util.parseJson(response);
```

The exception that stops the thread comes from a json error on the next step because the returned json is empty, even though the request clears through. I can get a proper json using just "me" or "me/albums" or anything other than "me?fields=cover". When I comment out the last line, 'try' process finishes with no exceptions/errors.

Is there something wrong with the Facebook API or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What response exactly are you getting? Is it just {"data": []}?

Comment: I don't even think I get that much. I get a json line 0 error and when I display the string in a text view it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer using FQL when dealing with User Profile. If you would like to give FQL a try, check the following piece of code. If you would like to stick to Graph API, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12434640/450534

```
try {
    String query = "SELECT pic_cover FROM user where uid = " + PUT_THE_USER_ID_HERE;
    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("method", "fql.query");
    param.putString("query", query);

    String response = Utility.mFacebook.request(param);

    JSONArray JAUser = new JSONArray(response);

    for (int i = 0; i < JAUser.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject JOUser = JAUser.getJSONObject(i);

        // COVER PHOTO
        if (JOUser.has("pic_cover"))    {

            String getCover = JOUser.getString("pic_cover");

            if (getCover.equals("null"))    {
                String finalCover = null;
            } else {
                JSONObject JOCoverSource = JOUser.optJSONObject("pic_cover");

                if (JOCoverSource.has("source"))    {
                    String finalCover = JOCoverSource.getString("source");
                } else {
                    String finalCover = null;
                }
            }

        } else {
            String finalCover = null;
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

The above code already accounts for User's who do not have a *Cover Photo* set in their profiles and checks for its availability. With this code, you will have the `URL` to the Cover Photo and can then process it as you prefer.

**NOTE:** If you are fetching the logged in users cover photo, this piece of code `SELECT pic_cover FROM user where uid = " + PUT_THE_USER_ID_HERE;` can also be written as: `SELECT pic_cover FROM user where uid = me()";` For the non-logged in user's cover photo, the above can be used as is.

Couple of things as a side note.

1. I use [Fedor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95313/fedor) Lazy Loading technique to load images in almost exclusively.
2. I recommend running the code block, mine or any other solution you choose, in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about using FQL, but Graph seemed simpler and easier, which led me to believe it would perform better. Is there a reason you prefer using FQL for user profiles or just in general? I'll give this method a try tonight.

Comment: @Wenger: No particular reason really. When I stared using the Facebook API, I was comfortable with SQL queries and hence I prefer FQL. I do use the Graph API calls for feeds and stuff, but mostly FQL. I also have a Graph API method linked to one of my answers. It's a little different than conventional Graph API calls but works like a charm everytime. I use that convention in my app for paging with endless lists.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not getting any result can be found in the javadoc of request(String graphPath) method:

> (...) this method blocks waiting for a network response, so do not
>   call it in a UI thread.

In your case, you should probably do the following synchronous call:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "cover");
String result = Utility.facebook.request("me/", params);
```

Siddharth Lele is very correct in his answer, but I wanted to specify the actual reason for not getting any response in this case.

Comment: This only returns the object id of the cover photo.  It does not return the url of the cover photo.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Fetching Cover Photo using Facebook API and endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=cover` no longer works as on 20th Dec 2014.

It was supposed to give following response:

```
{
   "cover": {
   "cover_id": "10151008748223553",
   "source": "http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/391237_10151008748223553_422785532_n.jpg",
   "offset_y": 0
   },
   "id": "19292868552"
}
```

But now it just gives User's `id`:

```
{
  "id": "19292868552"
}
```

Verified this using [Graph Tool explorer v2.2](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) using `me?fields=cover`.